# Customizing the theme for Metal LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager

Currently my application is running on Windows environment and as per new requirement we need port on Linux.

But my application is using the Windows look and feel which is only supported on windows platform and I am getting exception listed below when I run it on Linux.

I am facing the issues like component size mismatch and button colors when I planned to go ahead with GTK Look and feel.

Then I went Metal look and feel with my own theme, but still application is throwing the same exception.

```
MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(MyTheme());
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");

public class MyTheme extends DefaultMetalTheme {

    public String getName() {
        return "MyTheme";
    }
    ColorUIResource primary1 = new ColorUIResource(0, 78, 115);
    ColorUIResource primary2 = new ColorUIResource(102, 193, 122);
    ColorUIResource primary3 = new ColorUIResource(153, 244, 173);
    ColorUIResource secondary1 = new ColorUIResource(196, 172, 134);
    ColorUIResource secondary2 = new ColorUIResource(209, 192, 163);
    ColorUIResource secondary3 = new ColorUIResource(223, 211, 190);
    private final FontUIResource controlFont = new FontUIResource("Dialog", 0, 11);

    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary1() {
        return primary1;
    }

    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary2() {
        return primary2;
    }

    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary3() {
        return primary3;
    }

    protected ColorUIResource getSecondary1() {
        return secondary1;
    }

    protected ColorUIResource getSecondary2() {
        return secondary2;
    }

    protected ColorUIResource getSecondary3() {
        return secondary3;
    }

    public FontUIResource getControlTextFont() {
        return controlFont;
    }
}


INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 | Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(BasicButtonUI.java:352)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1714)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1636)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1716)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.FlowLayout.minimumLayoutSize(FlowLayout.java:448)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1636)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1716)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:1094)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:893)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2052)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2008)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(GridBagLayout.java:789)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:669)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:124)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:642)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:612)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Can you supply example code that can reproduce this error?

Comment: It's huge application which contains more than 1000 java classes. can you just give suggestion like how to overcome look and feel on  Linux platform?

Comment: The problem is, some how you've effected the core API classes in some way which I doubt we could replicate on our own. You need to supply a runnable example that demonstrates the problem so we can dig around and see what we can find. Given that people run Java on Linux all the time, we can suggested that it's likly to be an isolated problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing the look and feel for JButton to support linux platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561161/customizing-the-look-and-feel-for-jbutton-to-support-linux-platform)